# how to specialize a template constructor

Tags: c++, templates, partial, specialization, class-constructors

I'm able to specialize constructors fine:

```
template < typename TType >
class Field
{
public:
    Field( const Msg& )
        : _type( TType() )
    { }

protected:
    TType    _type;
};

template < >
Field < double >::Field( const Msg& msg )
    : _type( msg.extractDouble() )
{
}

template < >
Field < int >::Field( const Msg& msg )
    : _type( msg.extractInt() )
{
}
```

However, i need to do the same on a template that takes a non-type argument, such as:

```
template < const char* pszName, typename TType >
class Field
{
public:
    Field( const Msg& )
        : _type( TType() )
    { }

    static void setup( const Descriptor& d ) { // called once to setup _nIndex based on Descriptor and pszName 
    static int  index() { return _nIndex; }

protected:
    TType              _type;   // This class can only be sizeof TType in size

    static int         _index;
};

template < >
Field < ??, ?? >::Field( const Msg& msg )     // This doesn't compile
    : _type( msg.extractDouble( index() ) )
{
}

template < >
Field < ??, ?? >::Field( const Msg& msg )        // This doesn't compile
    : _type( msg.extractInt( index() ) )
{
}
```

Is there a trick to do this? I guess i could pass the const char name during setup() at runtime.  But it would be neat if the object itself knew without assistance.

Comment: I see no reason for this partial specialization (even if it were allowed). The float will get converted to double or int implicitly.

Comment: for my real needs the argument will be a more complex type.  For the sake of simplicity i made it a POD.

Comment: @edwinc: Will the argument have a conversion operator to the target type?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you cannot partially specialize functions, and a constructor is a function. You either fully specialize them or not at all.

A common solution to this problem is to use tag dispatch, however in your specific use-case it's a little simpler... use a `static_cast`

```
template < typename TType, int n >
class Field
{
public:
    Field( float f )
        : _type( static_cast<TType>(f) )
    { }

protected:
    TType    _type;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a1630d4217a9d07)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have done partial specialization of methods in the past.  Are you saying this can't be done when a template argument are values?  My real needs though are along the lines:

Comment: @edwinc you probably partially specialized a struct. It's never been possible for methods.